# Vagrant bash aliases not updating

Tags: bash, vagrant, homestead

When I first initialized my vagrant box, I added some aliases to `/vagrant/aliases` which is automatically copied to `/home/vagrant/.bash_aliases` on each provision.

What I added at first worked pretty well for the first few months, then I decided to add some more. The new aliases aren't working at all.

I tried reprovisioning the box, and I SSH'd to the box to check the `~/.bash_aliases` file and I can see all my new aliases are in there as expected...however, trying to use one of the new aliases produces a `command not found` error. All the old aliases still work.

What might be going on here?

Comment: Have you tried adding them to `~/.bashrc`? That might just be a distribution specific thing, but that's where I put mine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve this, execute `. ~/.bashrc` on the command line.

Then add the following to the bottom of `~/.bash_profile` so that the aliases are loaded each time you SSH to the vagrant box:

```
if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also try to provission your VM again, you can do this typing

```
vagrant global-status
```

This will give you information about your virtual machines, each one of them has an specific ID, find the one that's running homestead, it should look like this

```
id       name    provider   state    directory                                        
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1a2b3c4  default virtualbox running /home/dimitri/.composer/vendor/laravel/homestead
```

To provision again your VM and make the aliasses work without destroying your VM and creating it agait just run this command

```
vagrant provision 1a2b3c4
```

Keep in mind that the number at the end is the ID of your running VM